# How can I use a variable if condition inside the where clause?

Tags: python, sqlite

I use Python and SQLite
I want to use local variable condition in string query.
How do I do this like below?

```
A = 0
B = 0
"""Select * from TABLE where (TABLE.FIELD = ? OR A = 0) AND (TABLE.FIELD = ? OR B = 0) ..... """
```

${A} == 0 and ${B} == 0

Comment: Are you asking how to dynamically set `TABLE.FIELD`, or how to dynamically set `A` and `B`?  Or both?